# Searching for Patient within a Bundle

Tags: hl7-fhir

We use Bundles to contain other resources.  I want to search for bundles based on these nested resources.  e.g. I have bundles that look like this:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "type": "collection",
    "entry": [
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Patient",
                "identifier": [
                    {
                        "type": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "code": "foo"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "value": "12345"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": {
                            "coding": [
                                {
                                    "code": "bar"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "value": "abcde"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "SomeOtherResource"
            }
       }
    ]
}
```

I want to find all bundles which have `Patient` with `"bar" == "abcde"`.  There will be many such bundles and each Patient will have many identifiers other than "bar"

I've looked through https://www.hl7.org/fhir/search.html, but all the examples I find assume that (e.g.) Patient is at the top level and I can search with `[base]/Patient?...`, but I am looking for Bundles.  I've looked through the [search parameters here](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/bundle.html#search) but those don't include any "contained" entries.

I've tried all the combinations of bundle/patient/identifier I can think of with no luck.  Is this even supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Bundle is a FHIR Document or FHIR Message, you can search by chaining through the 'composition' or 'message' search parameter.  Otherwise, there's no standard way to search.  In general, content within a Bundle is opaque.

Comment: lloyd-mckenzie - that's what I was afraid of.

Comment: What is your objective in storing the data in a Bundle?

Comment: We didn't anticipate needing to search within the bundles, so it made sense... at the time.